# How can I disable binary distributions using setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools

I've seen various messages while running `pip` that say

> skipping bdist_wheel for X due to binaries being disabled for it

I have a package for which I want to disable binaries because there is some dynamic stuff done in setup.py. How can I do this?